# Embedded Linux -> saving application logs to File

Tags: linux, shell, logging, embedded, file-descriptor

You may see the question as a duplicate, but please read till the end.

I have an application running on the embedded Linux and I want to capture all the logs from the application. I tried with the with file descriptors as 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr. I was able to capture stderr logs. I want to capture the logs with the **printf** statement. The application is already built so I can not change it. It is embedded Linux so it does not have **script** utility.
My application have **printf** logs. All I want is to capture them using shell command if any.
I have tried below commands

```
./application 2>&1 | tee file.txt
./application >cmd.log 2>&1
./application | tee log.txt
```

With these commands I was able to capture error messages but not the printf messages

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Your first two command lines should actually catch everything that is sent (via `printf`, `puts`, whatever) to `stdin` and `stderr` (the last command line misses the latter).

If there are still messages printed to the console or tty, the application either redirects (using `dup2`, for example) `stderr` and/or `stdout` to some other device or it doesn't send its output to these two FILEs at all (*glibc*, for example, is known to write directly to the console device in certain error cases).

Without knowing where that output is actually sent to, it's impossible to catch it. `strace`ing the application could be used to find out where these strings are being sent to.

Comment: They should if the shell is something like bash which supports that mechanism, but on an embedded device the shell could be more primitive.  It's also possible the application is directly writing to /dev/console or something like that.

Comment: Hi tofro, Chris,
Thanks for suggestions.
I am now redirecting the stdout to test file using below function as
freopen("output.txt", "a+", stdout); 
But I want to dispaly the stdout on console while capturing / redirecting it to File.